# how to give _apt user permission to /var/lib/apt/lists?

Tags: apt, package-management, permissions

I am on `Ubuntu 18.04`. Every `apt update && apt upgrade` results in

```
W: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

I am aware that this has [come up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908800/what-does-this-apt-error-message-download-is-performed-unsandboxed-as-root). My problem is that as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1205517/657407), I *already* have

`/var/lib/apt/lists`

owned by `_apt:root`, recursively: I've already run

```
sudo chown -Rv _apt:root /var/lib/apt/lists
```

And `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` is chmodded `700`, so `_apt` should have write access fine.

**Additional info:**

This all started when I symlinked `/var/lib` elsewhere, to a directory under `/root/`.

I had to do this because although I have root access, the machine was set up by someone else at work with `/var` as a separate partition. It was too small and got full, so the move+symlinking was the solution at the time.

**Edit**

Following the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328915/657407), I moved the symlink target from under `/root/`; the warning is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you symlink things, you have to do permissions analysis on the **location that the symlink points to**.

If you moved `/var/...` into `/root` then anything accessing `/var/...` needs to be able to read `/root` - which only `root` can do.  Any chmodding you do on the symlink ***will do nothing***.

You should move back your `/var/...` with the original permissions it had back to where it should be and not symlink it.  This will break many potential things since by default only `root` can read `/root`.

You may want to consider expanding the `/var` partition rather than 'symlinking' stuff around, it's going to break the way you're doing things.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to sort it out as you suggest.