# Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file

Tags: apt, permissions

I'm trying to install Rocker Chat which I downloaded from the official GitHub repository.
I do this command:

`sudo apt install ./rocketchat_2.17.11_amd64.deb`

After installation I get this message:

```
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/deepdows/Downloads/rocketchat_2.17.11_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

When I try to run the rocketchat-desktop I get:

```
[bugsnag] Loaded!
[24506:0420/152301.161454:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(986)] The display compositor is frequently crashing. Goodbye.
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

But if I do `rocketchat-desktop --disable-gpu-sandbox` It will run just fine.

**I already tried**

```
sudo chown _apt /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/
```

```
sudo chmod -Rv 700 /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
```

```
sudo chmod -Rv 755 /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
```

```
sudo chown -Rv _apt:root /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/
```

```
sudo chmod 777 rocketchat_2.17.11_amd64.deb
```

**Nothing worked**

Comment: The apt download sandbox has nothing to do with this rocketchat GPU sandbox. They're completely unrelated.

Comment: why is there `couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)` error then?

Comment: It's not an error, it's not even a warning. It's just an informational note (`N:`)

Comment: well even if so, how can I run rocketchat in a normal way?

Comment: That's the part you should be focusing the post on. Add information relevant to that, like your GPU, Ubuntu version, kernel version, graphics driver version, whether you're running X11 or Wayland, etc.

Comment: The problem appeared after upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, 64-bit, GNOME 42, X11, kernel 5.15.0-25-generic, NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]

Answer (score 40):

That means `_apt` user does not have access to the downloaded apt file.

This is often due to the fact that the `Downloads` folder is by-default inside the `/home/user` folder - in your case `/home/deepdows` - and that folder is by-default non-readable by others.

Just move `rocketchat_2.17.11_amd64.deb` to `/tmp` for example, and install from there: you will get rid of that warning.

Comment: I didn't have this problem before upgrading to 22.04 (I had 21.10)
I also have already tried what you suggest, I don't have the warning, but still, the app is not running

Comment: Same here. Ubuntu lts 20.04 running from wsl2 didn't give me that warning, while 22.04 lts, clean ubuntu install, shows it.

Comment: After copying to /tmp it worked for me. By the way, I am not using rocketchat, it worked for other deb file

Comment: I had the same Information [N]ote on `Ubuntu 20.04` when installing `opera-stable_87.0.4390.25_amd64.deb` not from `~/Downloads` folder but from another partition. Nevertheless after such installation Opera worked normally.

Comment: Fresh install of Ubuntu 22.10.  Downloaded debs for VSCode, DBeaver, and Docker Desktop to ~/Downloads.  Installed with `sudo apt install ./thefile.deb`.  I get the same error, but the package still gets installed and works.