# How to give camera access to zoom?

Tags: software-installation, permissions, webcam, camera, zoom-meeting

I just installed zoom by downloading the deb file from here https://zoom.us/download.
Then I installed it using

```
$ mv ./zoom_amd64.deb /tmp  # See https://askubuntu.com/a/1416892/156688
$ cd /tmp
$ sudo apt-get install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

But when I open a zoom session, it is not able to access my camera. I tried to go to `Settings->Applications->Zoom` but there is no "Use your camera" option there, see screenshot below:

[image]

For comparison, skype works fine and can use my camera. The `Settings->Applications->Skype` page looks like this:

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

Check the ownership and permissions of the camera `ls -l /dev/video*`. Note that the camera grants `rw` access to the owner (`root`) and to members of the `video` group.

Adding yourself to the `video` group is the solution to your problem.

It's a two step process:

First,

```
sudo adduser $USER video
```

Then, logout. Login again (`login` sets up group memberships).

Use the `id` command to ensure that you have `video` group membership.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is still not working. I have added myself to the video group, and logged out and back in. Output of id command is now: `uid=1000(hakon) gid=1000(hakon) groups=1000(hakon),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare),137(libvirt),999(docker)`

Comment: I think it might be a more general problem with the webcam. I tried the `cheese` application and it also shows a black screen (camera not working). But I know that the camera is working since I have had microsoft teams sessions (from the web browser, google chrome) then the camera is working fine.

Comment: I also tried this online webcam test https://www.onlinemictest.com/webcam-test/ from both chrome and firefox and they both show the FPS count, but no video (black screen).

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].