# rtw89_8852ae on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS fails unexpectedly

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, lenovo

On `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS` with `6.2.0-36-generic` on a fresh installed device, the rtw89_8852ae fails unexpectedly and increassing in latency.

This is on syslog:

```
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829087] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW status = 0x74008000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829101] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW BADADDR = 0x0
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829108] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW EPC/RA = 0x0
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829114] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW MISC = 0xb898e663
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829120] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_HALT_C2H = 0x1000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829126] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_SER_DBG_INFO = 0xf500001e
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829136] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe8b
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829237] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898feb1
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829338] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898feb3
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829390] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff7f
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829441] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fead
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829492] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff9b
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829544] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898feb1
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829595] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff99
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829646] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe9d
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829696] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff83
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829714] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe3f
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829732] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fea5
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829750] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe9b
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829768] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe87
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829785] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff91
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829801] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: --->
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829801] err=0x1000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829807] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_SER_DBG_INFO =0xf500001e
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829816] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_DMAC_ERR_ISR=0x00000040
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829822] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_DMAC_ERR_IMR=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829827] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_WDE_ERR_FLAG_CFG=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829834] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_PLE_ERR_FLAG_CFG=0x83190000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829840] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_WDE_ERR_IMR=0xffffffff
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829846] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_WDE_ERR_ISR=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829851] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_PLE_ERR_IMR=0xffffffdf
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829857] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_PLE_ERR_FLAG_ISR=0x02000020
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829863] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_WD_CPUQ_OP_0=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829868] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_WD_CPUQ_OP_1=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829874] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_WD_CPUQ_OP_2=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829879] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_WD_CPUQ_OP_STATUS=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829885] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_PL_CPUQ_OP_0=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829891] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_PL_CPUQ_OP_1=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829896] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_PL_CPUQ_OP_2=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829902] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_PL_CPUQ_OP_STATUS=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829907] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_RXDMA_PKT_INFO_0=0x80008121
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829913] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_RXDMA_PKT_INFO_1=0x80008000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829919] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_RXDMA_PKT_INFO_2=0x81268122
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829929] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_CMAC_ERR_ISR [0]=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829936] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_CMAC_FUNC_EN [0]=0xf000003f
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829942] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_CK_EN [0]=0xffffffff
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829949] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_CMAC_ERR_IMR [0]=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829955] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_RPQ_RXBD_IDX =0x00380038
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829961] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_DBG_ERR_FLAG=0x00000000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829966] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_LBC_WATCHDOG=0x00000081
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829970] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: <---
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.829974] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: SER catches error: 0x1000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.877117] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: firmware failed to ack for entering ps mode
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880133] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW status = 0x74008000
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880141] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW BADADDR = 0x0
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880147] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW EPC/RA = 0x0
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880152] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW MISC = 0xb898e663
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880157] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_HALT_C2H = 0x1001
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880161] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_SER_DBG_INFO = 0xf500001e
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880169] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fea5
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880220] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ffb3
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880237] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff9d
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880254] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe85
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880270] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe8d
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880286] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe95
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880303] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe9f
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880394] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff83
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880410] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff93
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880427] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff99
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880443] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ffa5
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880460] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ffa5
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880476] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898ff9b
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880493] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fea5
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880509] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb898fe99
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880523] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: SER catches error: 0x1001
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880750] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW status = 0x74008100
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880756] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW BADADDR = 0x0
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880760] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW EPC/RA = 0x0
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880765] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: FW MISC = 0xb898e663
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880770] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_HALT_C2H = 0x1002
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880774] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: R_AX_SER_DBG_INFO = 0xf500001e
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880783] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb893b4df
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880799] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb89355ad
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880816] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8936787
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880832] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb899a40d
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880849] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb893aa2d
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880865] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb893a89d
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880881] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb8980177
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880898] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb897bd97
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.880948] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb89b9245
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.881048] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb897dc17
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.881147] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb89c0dfd
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.881164] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb89b9487
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.881181] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb89394c5
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.881197] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb893a2c9
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.881215] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: [ERR]fw PC = 0xb897be11
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.881231] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: SER catches error: 0x1002
Nov  5 19:56:41 ideapad kernel: [ 1493.905154] rtw89_8852ae 0000:03:00.0: c2h class 1 func 3 not support
Nov  5 19:57:52 ideapad dbus-daemon[1589]: [session uid=1000 pid=1589] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract-3.service' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1000 pid=1645 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
Nov  5 19:57:52 ideapad systemd[1566]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Nov  5 19:57:52 ideapad dbus-daemon[1589]: [session uid=1000 pid=1589] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
Nov  5 19:57:52 ideapad systemd[1566]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Nov  5 19:58:02 ideapad dbus-daemon[688]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.104' (uid=1000 pid=2132 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome " label="unconfined")
Nov  5 19:58:02 ideapad systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Nov  5 19:58:02 ideapad dbus-daemon[688]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov  5 19:58:02 ideapad systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Nov  5 19:58:04 ideapad gvfsd[8951]: got no contact to IPC$
Nov  5 19:58:32 ideapad systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

This is from a ping output:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1178 ttl=57 time=66.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1179 ttl=57 time=3051 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1180 ttl=57 time=2031 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1181 ttl=57 time=1007 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1182 ttl=57 time=20.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1183 ttl=57 time=59.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1184 ttl=57 time=20.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1185 ttl=57 time=89.3 ms
```

As you can see the latency is increasing at the moment of the crash. I was able to relate it to https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89/issues/133 but I am unbale to undestand the fix.

Comment: First, check if you have the correct package installed `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install linux-firmware` Then and if that doesn't fix the issue, to carry out the suggested fix, you would look at the contents of `/lib/firmware/rtw89` and then compare this to the files listed here. Download the missing files and place them in the `/lib/firmware/rtw89` directory. If that doesn't work, create a backup of the existing files in `/lib/firmware/rtw89`, and then replace them all with the downloaded versions. If that doesn't work, restore the backup files. Reboot between changes for good measure.

Comment: Other than that, another option would be to download the `linux-firmware` package from a newer version of Ubuntu, extract the deb package, create a backup of the existing files in `/lib/firmware/rtw89` and try replacing the corresponding files and missing files from the downloaded package for the `/lib/firmware/rtw89` directory.

Comment: An example of a newer version would be [the one here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/amd64/linux-firmware/download).

Comment: Quick question, are you using the lwfinger version or the default version from Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add a link in the first comment. [The files are listed here.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtw89)

Comment: They're referring to the last paragraph of the [README.md file](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89/blob/main/README.md) from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89/tree/main).

Comment: @mchid OP is using the in-kernel version rtw89_8852ae not the lwfinger version rtw_8852ae. I think the lwfinger version might be better.

Comment: @chili555 Yeah, it looks like they claim the problem was fixed in one of the more recent updates for the lwfinger version.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that we try the git version of the driver. With a working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git bc dkms dh-sequence-dkms debhelper build-essential devscripts
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
git deborig HEAD
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
sudo apt install ../rtw89-dkms_1.0.2-3_all.deb
```

This may produce an informational message:

> Download is performed unsandboxed as root etc.

However, this is not an error and is non-fatal. Reference: [What does this apt error message ("Download is performed unsandboxed as root...") mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908800/what-does-this-apt-error-message-download-is-performed-unsandboxed-as-root)

Blacklist the in-kernel driver:

```
sudo -i
echo “blacklist rtw89_8852ae” >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

I believe the later versions of *linux-firmware* include the needed firmware. Reboot. If the wireless isn’t working, please run and post:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i rtw
```